# Magento cache showing old product images on page zoom

Tags: magento-enterprise, cache, product-images, enterprise-1.14

So I've updated a product image, I've cleared the image cache, css/js cache, and the magento caches. When you zoom in and out on the page, the browser functionality, the images change back to the old images and stays as this old image until you refresh again.

I've also cleared the browser caches to make sure it's not the browser, and tried a browser that has never visited the page, incognito etc.

I've checked the product and the new images are set on the default and store level.

How can I get Magento to clear this cache properly?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with Magento using the old images because of the sort order, once the sort order was updated and then the old products excluded the cache stopped looking for the old images.